# ¿De qué forma obtengo una lista de objetos persistentes en DevExpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Intento obtener una lista de objetos persistentes en DevExpress.

Estos objetos son de tipo `Libro` y están declarados de esta forma:

```
public class Libro : XPBaseObject
{
    public Libro(Session session) : base(session) {}
}
```

Donde puedo buscar un libro en específico, de esta forma:

```
var libro = session.GetObjectByKey<Libro>(1);
```

Pero, necesito obtener una lista de todos los libros existentes en mi base de datos y colocarlos en una lista. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
List<Libro> libros = new List<Libro>();

for (int i = 0; i < cantidadLibros; i++)
    libros.Add(session.GetObjectByKey<Libro>(i));
```

El problema es que solo funciona con una cantidad fija de libros, y necesito que traiga todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En DevExpress, [`session.GetObjectByKey`](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.Session.GetObjectByKey--1(System.Object)) se usa para buscar un objeto persistente por su valor de propiedad clave. Este método busca, en el conjunto de datos, entre todos los objetos, aquel que sea del tipo especificado y cumpla el criterio especificado, por lo que de la forma en que lo haces es incorrecto, pues estas repitiendo esta acción por cada iteración.

Entiendo que lo que buscas es [`session.Query`](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.XPQueryExtensions.Query--1(DevExpress.Xpo.Session)) que es un método de extensión de `Session` y está disponible al importar `DevExpress.Xpo`. Este método devuelve un tipo [`XPQuery<T>`](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.XPQuery-1) que implementa `IEnumerable<T>` y permite la construcción de consultas `LinQ` sobre objetos persistentes.

Sabiendo esto, tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
XPQuery<Libro> query   = session.Query<Libro>();
List<Libro>    libros  = query.ToList();
```

O simplemente

```
List<Libro> libros = session.Query<Libro>().ToList();
```

<sup>No olvides importar `System.Linq` y `DevExpress.Xpo`.</sup>

---

Si deseas obtener la lista solo si existen elementos, y en caso contrario mostrar un mensaje, puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

<sup>Como he dicho antes, `XPQuery<T>` implementa `IEnumerable<T>`, por lo que puedes hacer uso del método `IEnumerable<T>.Any()`.</sup>

```
XPQuery<Libro> query = session.Query<Libro>();

if (query.Any())
{
    // Obtienes tu lista
    List<Libro> libros = query.ToList();
}
else
{
    // Muestras el mensaje, por ejemplo
    Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowMessage("No hay libros");
}
```

---

Como alternativa a `Session` puedes usar un `ObjectSpace`, que presenta el método [`IObjectSpace.GetObjects`](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/DevExpress.ExpressApp.IObjectSpace.GetObjects--1(DevExpress.Data.Filtering.CriteriaOperator)), el cual, devuelve un `IList<T>`, tal que así:

```
IList<Libro> libros = ObjectSpace.GetObjects<Libro>();
```

Y por supuesto, `IList<T>` implementa `IEnumerable<T>`, por lo que conserva la posibilidad de emplear los métodos de extensión de `System.Linq`.

```
List<Libro> libros = ObjectSpace.GetObjects<Libro>().ToList();
```

Comment: Me funciono, pero necesito que lo haga solo si hay libros y si no mandar un mensaje como puedo hacerlo

Comment: @user327824 Edité mi respuesta y agregué lo que preguntaste acá, por favor, echa un vistazo

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono